# Question about subs in MapBasic

Tags: mapinfo, mapbasic

For some reason my sub isn't 'linking' in MapBasic, I'm pretty new to this, but why is the sub assuming it begins on line 110 rather than where it actually says sub?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Try `End Sub` not `end sub`

Comment: Nope, still doing it :S

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it! It didn't like the word 'Type', I remedied it by putting the file type on the same line as export

Comment: If this has resolved your issue you can mark your own answer aa the accepted answer to indicate that this question has been resolved.

Comment: Type is a reserved word in MapBasic. http://reference.mapinfo.com/software/mapbasic/english/12.0/MapBasicUserGuide.pdf#page=52&zoom=auto,0,431